# Zoom functionality for iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, zooming, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing an iPhone Application, now I want to add Zoom in - Zoom out feature in some of my views (I want to add zoom effect for UITableview and UITextview). Please provide me some good tutorials or some working codes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add a Zoom functionality in your app is to use a `UIScrollView`.

It supports zooming an panning.

Here is some sample code from Apple:

[ZoomingPDFViewer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in this case can i add scroll view to achieve my need ?

Comment: You did not say what you want to do. You want the `UITableView` to zoom or the Cells to zoom?